# Replace css class in nested element

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to be able to remove class "ui-btn-active" from one anchor tag and add it to the other. This is done automatically by clicking the navbar button (jQuery Mobile), but I have a shortcut from Month to Day that doesn't trigger the class change. How can I do this elegantly without resorting to looping through the DOM and use string matching (or regex), is that possible?

```
<header id="view-navigation-view" class="button-list">
<div data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar ui-mini" role="navigation">
    <ul class="ui-grid-a">
        <li class="ui-block-a">
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-inline" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" data-inline="true">
                <span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"><span>Day</span></span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-block-b">
            <a href="#" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-inline">
                <span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"><span>Month</span></span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</header>
```

This removes it, but how to do I add it to the other?

```
$('a.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active')
```

**edit**

I gave each anchor tag the same ID as the span innerText.

```
    var setActiveNavbarButton = function(buttonName) {
        $('a.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
        $('#' + buttonName).addClass('ui-btn-active');
    };
```

Comment: Add to the other? Which one?

Comment: Sorry, I mean having the option with span content Month being selected and changing to option with span content Day.

Comment: Basically detecting which anchor holds the span option Day? I'm interested in a more general solution as the number of nav buttons might increase in the future.

Comment: So you need to detect link with span with `Day` text in it, and then what?

Comment: Add the css class there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to add different ID for your two `<a..>` tags to access them easily, you can then do

```
<header id="view-navigation-view" class="button-list">
<div data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar ui-mini" role="navigation">
 <ul class="ui-grid-a">
    <li class="ui-block-a">
        <a id="link_1" href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-inline" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" data-inline="true">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"><span>Day</span>    </span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-block-b">
        <a id="link_2" href="#" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-inline">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"><span>Month</span></span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</header>
```

`$("#link_1").removeClass("ui-btn-active");`

`$("#link_2").addClass("ui-btn-active");`

Comment: Very nice! So simple I should've thought of that myself. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. you don't need to change any html.
Here is the working example:

```
$(".ui-block-a a").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
$(".ui-block-b a").addClass("ui-btn-active");
```